# How can I make IF ELSE type statement in excel formula bar?

Tags: excel, search, if-statement, nested, excel-formula

Id like to make nested IF statements to function like an IF/ELSE. It's not the most elegant solution but I want to just get it functioning before I can improve it.

heres psuedocode of what I'm trying to do

IF no ERROR do:
If condition = TRUE Search b4 for criteria given and divide by 10000,
If condition = FALSE, IF condition2 = TRUE, Search and b5 for criteria given and divide by 1000
IF condition2 =False, then display "ERROR"
If Error then display "".

I put the following into the formula bar:

=IFERROR(IF(CLIENT=TRUE,SEARCH(Search!$B$4,C6)+ROW()/100000,IF(WORK_ORDER=TRUE,SEARCH(Search!$B$5,D6)+ROW()/100000,"ERROR",)"")

I get an error saying function has too many arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you put the comma after "`ERROR`" at the wrong place (it should go after the closing bracket). Currently the second `IF` function has four arguments instead of three (the fourth argument is "undefined", but the comma implies that it exists). Also, you are missing the second closing bracket after "`ERROR`". You should close both IF statements.

Try this:

```
=IFERROR(IF(CLIENT=TRUE,SEARCH(Search!$B$4,C6)+ROW()/100000,IF(WORK_ORDER=TRUE,SEARCH(Search!$B$5,D6)+ROW()/100000,"ERROR")),"")
```

Unfortunately, I can't test it myself right now.

---

*Edit by Aprillion*: you can also press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to insert newlines in your formula to make it more readable (*it is also possible to copy&paste following formula directly into the formula bar, although not into a cell on a sheet where it would be split to multiple cells*):

```
=IFERROR(
IF(client,
   SEARCH(Search!$B$4, C6) + ROW() / 100000,
   IF(work_order,
      SEARCH(Search!$B$5, D6) + ROW() / 100000,
      "ERROR")),
"")
```

Comment: I think Anasatasia is correct re: comma position. Don't know whether this helps but when I have to work on compound, nested IF statements I find it useful to copy the statement to notepad and try the individual components in excel to error trap which bit of the statement is causing the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much!:). I've been sitting here for a while trying to figure out what was wrong with my syntax(I did catch the extra comma but not the closing brackets)